# How to get the uploaded (generated) file name in django

Tags: python, django

**models.py**

```
class client_users(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    birthday = models.DateField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='images/', default="noimage.png")
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

**views.py**

```
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                form.save()
            except:
                pass
            print(client_users.profile_image.field.pre_save)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'form': form})
```

[This is a picture of the saved files with a code generated by django, because he found an image with the same name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHN4g.png)

Since django generated the code after the name of the picture, i want to get the full file name after the upload so i can update my database, request.FILES['profile_image'] doesn't return the generated value, it returns the name of the file on the upload.

Any help, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set the static URL in the `urls.py`? if not try that first. and you cannot access the field unless after you access `instance = form.save()` then instance will release the `client_users.profile_image.path` in this case you didn't even define `client_users`?

if you want you can remove the try and except

```
instance = form.save()
```

then print with

```
print(instance.profile_image.path)
```

Comment: Yes it does return the path to the file, but when there is a duplication, like when two same users imported a file with the same name, django automatically renames the second file, and it ends it with a random string expression like, (image_VdsPdsM.jpeg)  and that's what i want to get, the filename renamed by django after the upload

Answer (score 0):

Can you try accessing `client_users.profile_image.path`?

Comment: this is what i get `AttributeError: 'ImageFileDescriptor' object has no attribute 'path'`